# Qt add Widget to GraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Is there a way to draw Widgets on QGraphicsView instead of QGraphicsScene so that the widget stays in position when the scene is moved?

I want to create some dialogs that are dockable inside the workspace like this:

[image]http://www.thebandfrom.com/wp-content/uploads/photoshop-ui.png

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`addWidget`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) function of `QGraphicsScene`, and then set the [`QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) flag to the added `QGraphicsProxyWidget`.

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget* proxyWidget = scene->addWidget(myWidget);
proxyWidget->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add widgets onto the `QGraphicsView` directly by setting the `QGraphicsView` as their parent. You could also add a layout so that when the `QGraphicsView` is resized, your widgets arrange themselves appropriately.